# Command-L "Clear to the previous mark" equivalent in iTerm2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, iterm2

In Mac OSX there is the command-L command to "clear to the previous mark"

I was curious if there is a command equivalent to this in the iTerm2 terminal because I would like to switch over, but I use this command a lot in the normal terminal.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: what is previous mark?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679776/how-do-i-clear-delete-the-current-line-in-terminal

Comment: Sounds like a known issue https://superuser.com/questions/1178934/iterm2-ctrl-c-doesnt-work-sometimes

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733312/iterm2-delete-line

Comment: @KenRatanachaiS. previous mark is usually the last line the cursor is at. You can obviously mark/unmark places as you wish, https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/keyboard-shortcuts-trmlshtcts/mac#trmlcbe3aa09

Answer (score 2):

#### Cmd + Alt + L

I stumbled upon this when my finger slipped trying to perform something else.

```
Cmd + Alt + L
```

I find it really useful. Clearing the entire screen erases some useful output. Clearing one line at a time allows me to bring the cursor to a happier medium.

Thank you to whoever implemented this (though I can't find documentation on it)!

- https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/7343

Comment: Hmmm, this works on the latest Mac OS but not Mac OS 10.15

Answer (score 1):

Clear the screen/pane (when `Ctrl + L` won't work) `⌘ + K`

Here's a [cheatsheet for iTerm2](https://gist.github.com/squarism/ae3613daf5c01a98ba3a).

Honestly, I think clearing lines this way is a bad habit. It's not universal.

If you have a injected proc in metasploit with a terminal, and you hit your habitual keyboard interrupt sequence of choice.... Well, keyboard interrupt in this context will kill your shell and could kick you out of the injected process. (So much for your exploit. Sure hope someone restarts that box without getting suspicious...) It took me a year to get out of this habit and I still catch myself. Same problems with commands that don't terminate on their own like `ping` without specifying a count. Do that in metasploit without doing `ping -c 4 <ip>` and you'll remember how screwed you are because you *have* to do an interrupt to stop it, and that interrupt *will* kill your session.

Instead, I would recommend using the `home` key, entering a comment character, then `enter`. **This has the added benefit of saving the long line in history.** You worked hard to type that line. There's probably some goodness in there you might need later. And, once in your history, you can arrow up to it and simply `home` and delete the `#` character. Think of it like an *arm/disarm* toggle.

In bash that would be `home` and `#`. Oddly enough, I don't see a comment character for iTerm2...

Anyhow, when `Ctrl + L` does't work) try `⌘ + K`. Considering using `home` *comment char* `enter` instead.

Comment: I'm disappointed there isn't an equivalent. `Cmd + L`-like behaviour would be really useful. Clearing the entire screen gets rid of too much.

Answer (score 0):

#### key binding to tput

This solution should work with any terminal (I've bound the action to `Alt ;`):

```
bindkey -s "^[;"    "tput cuu 2\n"
```